# How do I force map annotations to be displayed?

Tags: ios, ios6, uiview, mkmapview

I want to display annotations on my map, then selecting one of them.

```
- (void)someWebServiceCallbackWithResult:(NSDictionary *)mapPins {

    [mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];
    [mapView addAnnotations:[mapPins allValues]];

    for (Pin *p in [mapPins allValues]) {

      if ([p.name isEqualTo:@"Cafe-Derp"] && mapView.hidden == NO) {

        //selectedMapAnnotationView is returned as nil at this point
        MapAnnotationView *selectedMapAnnotationView = (MapAnnotationView *)[mapView viewForAnnotation:p];
        [self presentPopover:p inMapAnnotationView:selectedMapAnnotationView];
        }
    }
}
```

However `viewForAnnotation:` returns nil in the if statement.

This shouldn't happen because `addAnnotations:` should have automatically display all the pins on my map. The code will only work if I wait for a certain amount of time before calling `viewForAnnotation:` like this:

```
double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
  MapAnnotationView *selectedMapAnnotationView = (MapAnnotationView *)[mapView viewForAnnotation:p];
  [self presentPopover:p inMapAnnotationView:selectedMapAnnotationView];
});
```

Why is this the case? Is there a method on the map view that I should be calling to trigger it to refresh?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are supposed to use `viewForAnnotation` yourself. instead try this

```
[mapView selectAnnotation:p animated:YES];
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. That seems to be a better way – however, my annotations are still not loaded by the end of the method, so that call does nothing.

Comment: Do you mean annotations (as in the pins are not appearing on the map) or the callouts (the popup window that you get when you select a pin?

There are a few things to check. Is `allValues` returning the right array? Is your `viewForAnnotations` function returning the right thing?